# JavaScript replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not sure the square brackets are correct (although it has not yet failed some simple tests). I would also like to reduce and simplify this code to one line if practical. I think the code is self explanatory.

```
  str = str.replace(/[\n]/g,'<br>')
  str = str.replace(/[\t]/g,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square brackets are technically correct, but unneeded:

```
str = str.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

Also, since a new string is returned, you can chain the methods:

```
str = str.replace(/\n/g, "<br>").replace(/\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

For more information, you can read the MDN pages on [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

---

Though the above is one line, if wanted to combine it into one replace, you could, but in my opinion this is uglier and less clear:

```
str.replace(/(\n|\t)/g, function (s) { return (s === "\n" ? "<br>" : "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"); });
```

This could be useful though if you had a large set of simple replacements:

```
var map = {"\n": "<br>", "\t": "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"};
str.replace(/(\n|\t)/g, function (s) { return map[s]; });
```

The idea could be extended farther to automatically generate the regex instead of relying on changing it every time `map` is updated.

Comment: I agree. I like the chained example. Thanks for clarifying the square brackets. I like the last example too, I think I have seen something similar.

Comment: Since you don't actually need regular expressions here, I would do it this way: `str = str.split('\n').join('<br>').split('\t').join('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')`