# Multiple regex replacements

Tags: javascript, regex

I receive a string with a lot of characters that I don't need and I am trying to remove them and replace them with characters that I am able to work with. My current structure has me redefining the `var` multiple times which I feel is not efficient and can probably be done better. Please let me know of a more effective way I can do this.

I define the date then remove the unwanted characters then append the date to the "clean" string with and underscore:

```
var d = Date.now()
  var article = a.replace(/ |\./g, "_")
  article = article.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"")
  article = article.replace(/\$|\#|\[|\]/g, "")
  article = d + "_" + article
```

This does work but I am curious if there is a better way.

Comment: See [replace multiple patterns with individual replacements in one operation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12457/93149), esp. "the map-approach".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, since you already did so inside of your two last expressions, with the same replacement:

```
article = article.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"")
article = article.replace(/\$|\#|\[|\]/g, "")
```

I'm puzzled why you didn't simply put both in a unique regexp:

```
article = article.replace(/\r?\n|\r|\$|\#|\[|\]/g, "")
```

Then to integrate with the 1st one, you might choose to:

- join the two distincts replacements in a single line:

  ```
  var article = a.replace(/ |\./g, "_").replace(/\r?\n|\r|\$|\#|\[|\]/g, "")
  ```
- or use a map approach, either suche the one pointed by @greybeard's link, or like this way (even if it might look a bit too sohpisticated for only two cases):

  ```
  var replacements = new Map([
      [/ |\./g, '_'],
      [/\r?\n|\r|\$|\#|\[|\]/g, '']
      ]),
      article = a;
  replacements.forEach(function(value, key){
        article = article.replace(key, value);
      });
  ```

The most interesting aspect in this latter solution is that it may be easily expanded if more replacements are needed.

---

EDIT following a good suggestion from @Niet the Dark Absol.

As soon as there are several *unique* characters to look for, with the same replacement, this kind of regexp `/(a|b|c)/` can be replaced by `/[abc]/`, which is both simpler and more efficient!

Any of the above proposed solutions can be improved this way, so the latter one becomes:

```
    var replacements = new Map([
        [/[ .]/g, '_'],
        [/[\r\n$#[\]]/g, '']
        ]),
        article = a;
    replacements.forEach(function(value, key){
          article = article.replace(key, value);
        });
```

Comment: I would suggest improving that regex further. `/[\r\n\[\]$#]/g` is much more concise and works in the same way, and can have other options added to it easily enough.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Indeed you're right, and I should have noticed that! I'll edit my answer about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could define your pattern and replacement in an array. Then you can use `reduce` to carry the string through the array while replacing them.

```
let formatters= [
  {pattern: / |\./g, replacement: '_'},
  {pattern: /\r?\n|\r/g, replacement: ''},
  {pattern: /\$|\#|\[|\]/g, replacement: ''},
];

let article = formatters.reduce((a, f) => a.replace(f.pattern, f.replacement), a);
```

Comment: While this cleanly separates pairing patterns and replacements from using them in _replace_, it almost hides the time complexity of (avoidably) applying replace more than once.